# Why do I get a kernel panic when rebooting after installing via Wubi?

Tags: kernel, wubi, boot-failure

I installed Ubuntu from Windows.
When it tried to reboot, the computer started with the following text on the screen:

```
init[1]: segfault at ....
kernel panic - not syncing. Attempted to kill init! ...
....
panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

The computer then failed to start until I rebooted from a boot CD.
It then opened normally in Windows.

I installed from: [ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS

My hardware is as follows:

```
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5500 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
Video controller: NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS
```

I have not tried rebooting again.

Comment: reboot and verify error exist or not

Answer (score 0):

You say 'you tried to install Ubuntu from Windows'.  Please give more information.  What exactly (in detail) did you do to try to install?  What happens when you boot into the Ubuntu live-DVD and use the 'Try Ubuntu' option?  What version of Ubuntu are you trying?  What is your hardware, especially the video controller/chipset?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I installed from: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer  Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS

Comment: I don't have the Ubuntu live-DVD. My hardware is as follows:   OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Processor Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5500  @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
Video controller: NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS

Comment: That means that what you have is a wubi installation, not a native Ubuntu installation.  There are known issues with some nvidia controllers.  I strongly recommend that you download the live-DVD of 12.04 and boot into this.  It has a 'Try Ubuntu' option.  If that runs all your hardware OK, then 12.04 should be able to install - but not as a wubi installation obviously.